# How can i connect PHP to Oracle?

Tags: php, oracle

Can I connect PHP and oracle? Can you help with some books related to that?

Are they similar to how we use MSSQL and MySQL? For example:

```
Oracle_connect($dbhost,$dbport,$dbuser,$dbpass);
```

Comment: Here is the documentation from Oracle on how to perform this. It should behave very similar to how you handle MySQL requests.
https://blogs.oracle.com/alison/entry/oracle_database_connection_str Specifically what you're looking for is oci_connect()

Comment: yes means does it work with all version of oracle

Comment: That requires a bit more information. My guess is that if it exists, its supported. If you're using a specific version of Oracle you would need to look for the PHP library relevant for that version and then see if the api is then supported in your version of PHP.

Comment: this [link](http://zahidrouf.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/connect-php5-with-oracle-10g-windowsxp/) helped me alot. Hope you will find your answer here. It describes the complete configuration of oracle client with php using wamp

Answer (score -1):

first you need to Install PHP 5.3.3 with the OCI8 1.4 extension. In php.ini set:

`oci8.connection_class = MYPHPAPP`

and then out this code:-

```
<?php
// Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("phphol", "welcome", "//localhost/orcl");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

or simply check out this tutorial

http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/opensrclang/phphol2010_db/php_db.htm

Comment: does it support in all version of oracle

Comment: well i dont know for sure which exact versions are supported by php but starting with Oracle 10g has support for it.
download this free book about php and oracle its very usefull and straight forward http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen

Comment: Can you help with some more questions 1) In PHP how can i add an insert statement so that i will read on both master and slave.2) And how can i restart Slave through the script.

Comment: i think that does not involve anything related to specific php more like it relates to the DB specifactions and it is the same as anything useing oracle DB, use this tutorial it shows all php connections and all the codes to use http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/WebScriptingForOracle.php

Comment: _first you need to Install PHP 5.3.3 with the OCI8 1.4 extension_ -- How would one do this? Historically, installing PHP with OCI support  has required compiling your own version of libphp, which is not trivial and requires frequent manual updates.